# How do I search for files from the gnome GUI in debian?

Tags: files, gnome, search

I sometimes spend time in the standard classic gnome GUI in `debian wheezy`, and today I wanted to search for files containing some text in a certain folder.

I tried to do it the windows way by going to the folder I wanted to search in, clicking on "Search" and typing in the text. But when I press "Enter" all I see is a bar saying "Search Results", with the location I'm searching in and a little `+` icon to add criteria to my search. There's no results...

To confirm it's not finding anything I created a folder called `abc` on the desktop and placed a file called `text` into it. I then double-clicked the folder, clicked on `search`, typed "text" and got a blank results page (with only the aforementioned "Search Results" bar and an option to add other criteria).

Is this a bug, permission issue or a bad feature? And what's the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your system database I think with `updatedb` command

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what that means.

Comment: The `updatedb` command is used to update meta data for searching files with the `find` utility. I don't know if the gnome gui is using this command for file searching but you can try ... Just type in a shell the command to execute it and try again your research.

Comment: @Ko2r `find` doesn't use the "database" generated with `updatedb` it just searches the filesystem. `locate` is the utility that uses the data generated with `updatedb`.

Comment: @Anthon My mistake I mean `locate`